# Running 2 Tomcat Servers using different ports with intern() will lock same id or no?

Tags: java, string, multithreading, intern, synchronize

In my Tomcat server Java Code I'am using the following code:

```
int port = 11111;
rmiConnectToMainServer(port);
id = request.getParameter("id").intern();
synchronized(id) {
    //call SaleFunction();
}
```

and in another Tomcat Server Where the port in

```
int port = 22222;
```

The question is: Does the String.intern() call use another pool of strings?? or no??

lets say a clients that has id=1234 is buying from both Tomcat Server at the same time, will he be locked ??? or can buy without any lock ???

Please help me, my app is now online .. And I'm afraid If something is wrong.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One String pool per JVM, so as your Tomcat instances are running in different JVMs your `"id"` won't be shared.

Comment: So even if I'am running both Tomcat Servers on the same Server Manager with other or same port, The id won't be locked because i'm calling a different Tomcat project ??

Comment: Question 2: you If I was using the same java Server (for both Tomcat) with Same port it will use only 1 pool ??

Comment: If there's only one Java process running, but you somehow have 2 Tomcat servers running, they would share the String pool. Not that this is likely. I recommend coming up with a better way than synchronizing on a String to solve your problem.

Comment: What I need is to lock both tomcat for the same ID.. So What I did I correct  independent if I'am using the same port or not right ??

Comment: By the way Thanks a lot for your fast answer

Comment: You'll have to have some shared resource you can lock on. If you can identify the user reliably on both servers, you could maybe use a database table to "lock" the user only on one server at a time.

Comment: So each Tomcat Server will have his own pool of strings. Thanks.